# Modulo question about equality

Tags: modular-arithmetic

True or false?

$$24 \equiv 77 \mod 16 $$

$1.$ $77/16 = 4.8125 $

$2.$ $4.8125 - 4 = .8125$

$3.$ $0.8125 \times 16 = 13$

$4.$ $24 != 13$

So the answer is false? Am I right?

Comment: You are correct. yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler approach: $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ if and only if $n$ divides $(b-a)$.

In this problem, $77-24=53$, which is not a multiple of $16$ ($53/16=3.3125$), so $77\not \equiv 24\pmod{16}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Although we tend to avoid using decimals and fractions with modular arithmetic, and thus you just have to keep your integers as integers. This would've been a cleaner way of writing what you just did (the math is basically the same):
$$
77 = 64 + 13 = 4\cdot 16 + 13 \equiv 13 \not\equiv24 \mod{16}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Please, stop using fractions when evaluation of modulus...

$$24 \equiv 8 \mod 16$$

$$77 \equiv 13 \mod 16$$

thus your equation is not valid.

Comment: The OP's calculations were correct, this is a valid way of computing mod with a four-function calculator.

Comment: I know that it is a valid method, but it is ugly. And it doesn't have anything to do with modular arithmetics.

Comment: @V-X Please try to be patient with those first encountering modular addition (and in general, aim to be constructive).

Comment: 16 is a lucky number choice of a number, but e.g for 17 OP would need to perform rounding which would be much less educative... I think my request for not using fractions in whole number operation was not that impatient..

Comment: I think V-X is right here: the use of decimal fractions is fine...yes, as long as the calculator can contain **all** the decimal digits *and* there are not many operations to do, otherwise it could be that carried approximation errors would be decisive...Not a good idea, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\ \rm mod\,\ 2n\!:\ 24\equiv 77\,\Rightarrow\, mod\,\ 2\!:\ 24\equiv 77\,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv 1$